# Autocomplete for dynamically populated dictionary containing classes?

Tags: python, oop, dictionary, autocomplete

I have a GUI, and through it I load some data. When a file is loaded, its filename is used as an identifier, which populates the GUI and also a dictionary underneath, to keep track of the current state for each file.

However, with this approach I can't get any autocomplete from the `MetaData` class, e.g. when I want to access `data.container.[GUIcurrentFile].one_of_many_attributes`.

Is there a way around this? Perhaps keeping files in memory in an entirely different fashion? What do people normally do in this scenarios? I'm not too familiar with GUI development.

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = dict()

    def load(self, name):
        self.container[name] = MetaData()

class MetaData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.one_of_many_attributes = None


# This is instantiated in the main part of the GUI, e.g. self.data = Data()
data = Data()


## Series of events happening through the GUI
# Grab loaded file through a GUI
GUIcurrentFile = "file1"
data.load(GUIcurrentFile)

GUIcurrentFile = "file2"
data.load(GUIcurrentFile)

# Each file has separate attributes
data.container[GUIcurrentFile].one_of_many_attributes = "foo"

# File is removed from GUI, and can easily be removed from dictionary internally
data.container.pop(GUIcurrentFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so type hinting finally clicked for me. I hope the original title makes sense, in relation to this answer. Else, feel free to edit it.

Defining MetaData first, it's very straight forward to add type hinting for PyCharm, if a method is implemented to return an object of type "MetaData".

```
class MetaData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = None
        self.really_long_name = None

class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = dict()

    def load(self, name):
        self.container[name] = MetaData()

    def get(self, name) -> MetaData: # specify what dict lookup returns
        return self.container[name]

data = Data()
data.load("file1")
data.get("file1").foo
```

[image]